# Extract data from a txt file that contains data blocks and strings using python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I need to postprocess an output file from a model using python. The output file has a combination of data and strings. First, I want to separate the strings from data and then save the columns 0,1 and 2 from each output time (only data, with no strings) in a separate text file. So, for the below example, I will have 3 text files (for Time=0, Time=0.01, Time=0.04) each containing data from each output time without any header or any other strings in them. The short form of the output file from model looks like this:

```
 ******* Program ******  
 ******* Program ******  
 ******* Program ******                                                   
 Date:  26. 4.    Time:  15:40:32
 Units: L = cm   , T = days , M = mmol 


 Time:     0.000000

 Node    Depth    Head   Moisture   HeadF  MoistureF      Flux   
      [L]      [L]     [-]       [L]       [-]       [L/T]   

   1     0.00   -1000.00 0.1088    -1000.00 0.002508  -0.562E-03 
   2    -0.04   -1000.00 0.1088    -1000.00 0.002508  -0.562E-03 
   3    -0.08   -1000.00 0.1088    -1000.00 0.002508  -0.562E-03 
end


 Time:     0.010000

 Node    Depth    Head   Moisture   HeadF  MoistureF      Flux   
          [L]      [L]     [-]       [L]       [-]       [L/T]   

   1     0.00    -666.06 0.1304      -14.95 0.139033  -0.451E-02 
   2    -0.04    -666.11 0.1304      -15.01 0.138715  -0.887E-02 
   3    -0.08    -666.35 0.1304      -15.06 0.138394  -0.174E-01 
end


 Time:     0.040000

 Node    Depth    Head   Moisture   HeadF  MoistureF      Flux    
          [L]      [L]     [-]       [L]       [-]       [L/T]    

   1     0.00    -324.87 0.1720      -12.30 0.157799  -0.315E-02  
   2    -0.04    -324.84 0.1720      -12.31 0.157724  -0.628E-02  
   3    -0.08    -324.83 0.1720      -12.32 0.157649  -0.125E-01  
end
```

I found the following code from another question which was posted in stackoverflow earlier. Here is the link to that question:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11712496/python-how-to-extract-specific-lines-of-data-from-a-big-text-file)

That problem is very similar to mine; however, I have problems modifying it to help solve my problem. How should I modify it for my problem? or should I use another strategy to approach this problem?

```
def parse_DPT(lines):
    DPT = []
    while lines:
        line = lines.pop(0).lstrip()
        if line == ' ' or line.startswith('*'):
            continue
        if line.startswith('*'):
            lines.insert(0, line)
            break
        data = line.split(' ')
        # pick only columns 0, 1, 2 and
        # convert to appropiate numeric format
        # and append to list for current DPT and step
        DPT.append([int(data[0]), float(data[1]), float(data[2])])
    return DPT

raw = []
with open('NOD_INFTEST.txt') as nit:
    lines = nit.readlines()
while lines:
line = lines.pop(0)

if line.startswith(''):
    if line.find('Time:') > -1:
        raw.append(parse_DPT(lines))

from pprint import pprint
for raw_step in zip(raw):
    print 'raw:'
    pprint(raw_step)
```

Here is the error message that I get from python:

```
'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\python test\p-test3.py", line 58, in <module>
    raw.append(parse_DPT(lines))
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\python test\p-test3.py", line 35, in parse_DPT
    DPT.append([int(data[0]), float(data[1]), float(data[2])])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Units:'
```

Comment: What exactely are you trying to get as an end result? You say in the example below you have 3 files but I only see one. Where is the limit between them?

Comment: @IonutHulub Sorry if my explanation was confusing. By that sentence I meant that at the end, I want to have 3 separate text files that are created from the file that you can see above. Each section starts with the "Time: " and finishes with "end". I hope this helps with explanation.

Comment: And I'm guessing you want file one to contain this:`  1     0.00   -1000.00 
   2    -0.04   -1000.00 
   3    -0.08   -1000.00`

If not please provide the expected output for the example you gave.

Comment: @IonutHulub that is exactly what I expect as file one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question then this code should do the trick:

```
import re

with open('in.txt', 'r') as in_file:
    file_content = in_file.read()
    blocks = re.findall(
        'Time:\s*\d+\.\d*(.*?)end',
        file_content,
        re.DOTALL
        )

    file_number = 1
    for block in blocks:
        with open('out%s.txt'%str(file_number), 'w') as out_file:
            for row in re.findall(
                    '\s*(-?\d+.?\d*)\s*(-?\d+.?\d*)\s*(-?\d+.?\d*).*',
                    block):
                out_file.write(row[0] + ' ' + row[1] + ' ' + row[2] + '\n')
        file_number += 1
```

The code assumes that the files containing the text is called `in.txt`

Comment: It exactly did what I needed. Thanks very much for your help. It just gives this message. Is this an error message?                  'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback

Comment: what message does it give?

Comment: it creates the files that I need and gives this message:  'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback

Comment: That error doesn't come from my scrip. I do not import sitecustomize. If you get the desired output files you shouldn't worry about it though. If you post your full code I can tell you why it gives that error.

Comment: I don't have any additional code and it still gives that error. I get the desired output files.

Comment: Since you don't have any aditional code I have no idea where that error comes from, but it's actually just a warning, not an error. Don't worry about it. The script will work just fine.